# How to select rows with multiple specific column values in single query?

Tags: mysql

Table A

```
itemNo   colorNo
1        3
1        4
2        4
2        70
3        9
3        10
```

I wanted to do this...

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE itemNo = '1' AND colorNo = '4';
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE itemNo = '2' AND colorNo = '70';
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE itemNo = '3' AND colorNo = '9';
```

But can I combine those 3 queries into one?

I tried to do this, but it only returned one row satisfying the last condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE ((itemNo = '1' AND colorNo = '4') 
or (itemNo = '2' AND colorNo = '70') 
or (itemNo = '3' AND colorNo = '9'));
```

EDIT: It turns out the table I got is faulty. The first two 'itemNo' didn't even exist! No wonder only the last one got returned. Thank you to everyone who helped! I'll leave this up here and hopefully it'll help someone with a similar question.

Comment: Your second query is perfect. [It returns three rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49f0ca/1). What's the problem now?

Comment: You can also use UNION, or OR conditions

Comment: Strange. I'm using HeidiSQL and it's giving me just one result. Maybe there's some differences between HeidiSQL and normal MySQL?

Comment: HeidiSQL is just another MySQL client. There is no reason for it to return different results for the same query on the same server.

Comment: There seems to be no need for all those inverted commas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT *
  FROM A
 WHERE (itemNo = '1' AND colorNo =  '4')
    OR (itemNo = '2' AND colorNo = '70')
    OR (itemNo = '3' AND colorNo =  '9')
```

or you can also do this

```
SELECT *
  FROM A
 WHERE (itemNo, colorNo) IN ((1, 4),(2, 70),(3, 9))
```

Output:

```
| ITEMNO | COLORNO |
--------------------
|      1 |       4 |
|      2 |      70 |
|      3 |       9 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49f0ca/5)** demo

Comment: This is the perfect query. But he has already tired the same. Don't know why he is not getting expected result.

Comment: @Rayf [Nope, the original query works perfectly.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49f0ca/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    A
WHERE 
    (itemNo = '1' AND colorNo = '4') OR
    (itemNo = '2' AND colorNo = '70') OR
    (itemNo = '3' AND colorNo = '9');
```

is that what you mean?